# Change CSS direct with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

What is currently the best and easiest way to change CSS style using javascript?
I have several elements on the page with `class="colorManipul"` and in css `.colorManipul{filter: grayscale(33%);}`
I want to change the value directly in CSS so that it is reflected on all required elements with this class
Thanks for the advice, link, example, ... just anything

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: If you can you should always use JS to add /remove CSS classes and not change the content of a CSS file. Anything else makes a debugging process harder. But if you insist, you should change the value of a `:root` variable declaration.

Comment: How about adding new class, for eg. `class="colorManipul some_other_class"`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of a CSS property with JS. To easily target a property you should target a CSS-Variable:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--body-bg', 'blue');
})
```

```css
:root {
  --body-bg: red;
}


body {
  background: var(--body-bg);
}
```

However, this is harder to debug and a cleaner solution is to simply add a class to all elements with a certain class.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.colorManipul').forEach(el => 
  el.classList.add('class-name')
);
```

Comment: Just a nitpick: `root.style.setProperty` sets the inline style of `<html>` element ; ). That's the way you usually use CSS variables, though.

Comment: @Teemu is correct but will not work here as the snippet has no external CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change percentage of grayscale value, you can use css variable and change its value from JS For example:

CSS:

```
:root {
  --grayscale: 33%;
}

.colorManipul {
  filter: grayscale(var(--grayscale));
}
```

JS:

```
const grayscaleValue = 50;
root.style.setProperty('--grayscale', `${grayscaleValue}%`);
```

Comment: why `50 + "%"` instead of `'50%'`

Comment: In case you want value to be stored in variable, it would be easier to have it as number and add css unit separately. `50%` is still completely correct. But `50 + "%"`makes it easier to change the value.

Comment: then use `backticks` and include a variable instead of an integer. Otherwise, if you include an integer then nothing will happen at that moment anyways.

Comment: I've updated my answer, even thou both ways of writing strings are correct. `grayscaleValue + "%"` is just older syntax.